# Past continous adverb placement

Tags: verbs, past-tense, adverbs, past-continuous

In the phrase:

> The stock scandal was extremely damaging to his company's reputation.

What is the verb tense? I think "was damaging" is past continuous and "extremely" is an adverb modifying "damaging". But is "damaging" actually an adjective? And then, the verb tense is past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb 'damage' needs a direct object to be a part of a Predicative Verb in such a sentence. That is why 'damaging' is a predicative adjective here. A tense of the Predicative Verb is the Past Simple in the grammar construction with the linking verb 'be' here.